# Removing Membership Status Message on Front End Webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

We recently sent out emails to our affiliates, providing them with a link outfitted with some checksum tokens. The link goes to a webform w/ CiviCRM Integration. The token and webform work fine -- they are able to fill out the required information and pay for their membership.

Some users, however, are getting confused by the message "x membership has a status of 'x'" at the top of the webform page, thinking that their membership is expired, cancelled, etc. based on what they see.

The organization, before my arrival, had tried to set up the membership feature, however it was never fully realized, leading to me having to create a new set of membership types to work with. I've gone ahead and expired the old memberships, re-titling the type to "2013 Membership", however that still leaves the aforementioned message visible to the person utilizing the checksum link. I could just delete the old membership type, as we plan to do a fresh install in the future without this information, however we have payments associated with the membership type that I don't want to go down that route, yet.

I'm assuming I'll have to make the change somewhere in a template file, however I wanted to check first before I go messing around with it, in case I'm missing an option somewhere inside the front end of Civi.

Edit: Here is an example of the message users see. I'm interested in removing the first line in the green box. Users will not see the second line as this is a new webform that everyone will be submitting for the first time.

[image: Image of Membership Status on Webform]

Comment: i think it might help if you provide a screenshot, as that message on a webform page could be a number of things.

Comment: If you do decide to delete the membership types ask a question about how you can without loosing the contribution.  It can be done with a bit of sql.  Also, it might be possible with sql to change the membership type of the memberships that are "bad" to the "good" ones.

Comment: I've added an example image.

Comment: not sure - if you disable the membership type at civicrm/admin/member/membershipType?reset=1 does it lose the msg? does that work as a temporary workaround? ie you could reenable later if you need to

Comment: If you don't need either of those messages (membership or "already submitted") you could consider hiding them with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you disable the membership types you are no longer using in your system (per Pete's suggestion in the comments).

I've just [patched webform_civicrm](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/commit/96aa8693e2b1edc91b685199a821ea79e16f1d62) to ensure it takes this into account, so it will no longer display messages about disabled membership types. That will be included in the 7.x-4.16 release, for now you can upgrade to the -dev version of the module to get this new functionality.

Comment: Good to know. We currently use the webform-civicrm integration in a unique way that we're fortunately going to phase out in our upcoming redesign. Until then, I'm hesitant to update our version, for fear of breaking something. Thank you, however, for patching it should I (or someone else) run into this issue again in the future.